# Place cursor in messages app text box

Tags: macos, applescript, message

I am looking for a script that will place the cursor in the text field in the Messages App. I have looked for a keyboard shortcut to do this but cannot find one. Can anyone provide a script, or a similar one I can modify.

NB I am not a programmer or very familiar with AppleScript, but have been able to modify scripts that are close to my needs.

I need this as I am trying to make the messages app controllable using the built in dictation feature in Mac OS. I need a script I can assign to a voice command to place the cursor in the text field so that I can then dictate a message.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dictation commands, in any application all you need to do is say the command “Show Numbers”  and you will see this:

[image]

Then you would just say the command “Twenty” which will place your cursor right where you want it… in this case it would be the text field

---

Also speaking the command “Show Comands” Will open up this window listing tons of dictation commands.

[image]

Comment: For some inexplicable reason the show commands was not working on my messages app except for the header buttons. However, for some additional inexplicable reason, when I just tried it, it now works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have just tried this again. For some reason I do not always get all the fields numbered. It is very odd. When I first open messages it numbers correctly, but if I move the window it then misses off some numbers.

Comment: Dictation is nice but having to repeat verbal commands because of idiosyncrasies is a pain, I'd rather use my script as there is no ambiguity there, it does as it programmed to do. :)

Comment: Show numbers is very useful - but for repetitive tasks a script is much quicker. The key for me is reliability, which is not quite as good as it needs to be with some of the dictation commands. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have had some feedback on the numbers not appearing when using Show Numbers command. If the window is up against the left hand edge of the screen then the numbers do not appear. They do appear if you move the window away from the left hand edge. I think this is a known issue, so hopefully it will be fixed some time soon.

Comment: @AndrewK If you find any of the answers are helpful, please vote them up or mark them as accepted answer for your original question

Answer (score 0):

The following was tested and works under OS X 10.8.5 and Messages 7.0.1 and may need to be adjusted for other versions of OS X/macOS/Messages:

```
tell application "Messages"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        set focused of text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Messages" to true
    end tell
end tell
```

Note: This is coded with the assumption that Messages is already open with an open window. Additional coding will be necessary, in the form of `try` and or `delay` and or `on error` *statements* as needed and appropriate otherwise.

---

Here's an example of how I'd code it otherwise, which handles whether or not Messages is open, has its window showing, etc.

```
on setFocusToTextArea()
    tell application "System Events"
        if (count of windows of application process "Messages") is equal to 0 then
            click UI element "Messages" of list 1 of application process "Dock"
            delay 0.25
        end if
        try
            set focused of text area 1 of scroll area 4 of splitter group 1 of window 1 of application process "Messages" to true
        end try
    end tell
end setFocusToTextArea

tell application "Messages"
    if running then
        my setFocusToTextArea()
    else
        activate
        delay 2
        my setFocusToTextArea()
    end if
    activate
end tell
```

Note: If Messages is closed when this *script* is run, the `delay 2` *command* gives time for Messages to open before the other *code* runs. The *value* of the `delay` *command* can be adjusted as appropriate for the speed of your system.

Comment: I have tested the first script on 10.13 (Beta) and it works fine. Thank you! I should have said that I will always use this with messages open.

Comment: I have also tested the second script and this also works.